# How to reverse the order of value axis in clustered bar chart using python-pptx module?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

```py
cluster_bar_chart_data = CategoryChartData()

# Adding categories to chart
cluster_bar_chart_data.categories = df['period'].to_list()

# Adding series
cluster_bar_chart_data.add_series("A",(df["A"].squeeze()), number_format=None)
cluster_bar_chart_data.add_series("B",(df["B"].squeeze()), number_format=None)
cluster_bar_chart_data.add_series("C",(df["C"].squeeze()), number_format=None)

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(7), Inches(1.2), Inches(6), Inches(5.5)

cluster_bar_chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, x,y, cx, cy, cluster_bar_chart_data)
```

I am using the above code for creating a cluster bar chart with 3 series. Below is the output I am getting:
[image]

Expected Output:[image]

Is there any way to reverse the order of values at value axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chart.category_axis.reverse_order = True
```

Should do the trick. You can read more about that property of an axis in the API documentation here:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.axis._BaseAxis.reverse_order

Comment: I need to reverse the order of values displayed on the value axis as I mentioned in the expected output.

Comment: Ah, okay, you need to reverse the order of the _categories_ on the _category_ axis. I've changed the code. The category axis in these charts is the vertical axis. The value axis is the horizontal one.

Comment: This is doing the trick but along with that value_axis is going on the top which I don't want.

Comment: That's really a separate question and separate solution @Hiramanshu. If you accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer) and post a new question for that I'll address it there. Just make sure you use the `python-pptx` tag and I'll see it.